# How can I have a better MouseEvent implementation in my Component with Angular 4?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have this working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zm940D?p=preview) Example, you can drag the mouse and select the cards.

> My problem is that the code has alot of bugs and I want to do
>   something similar to this [Demo](http://maxazan.github.io/angular-multiple-selection/)

Here something that I want to fix ([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB1Cx.png) and [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2zP.png) - the cards in img #2 were clicked before), another thing is that if you drag the mouse fast sometimes the cards will not be select.

Here is my component code

```
export class App {

  private dragStart:number = 0;
  private dragOver:number = 0;
  public users:Array<{id?: number; name: string; admin: boolean;}> = [
        { name: 'Alexis Wursten', admin: false  },
        { name: 'Janco Boscan', admin: true  },
        { name: 'Noemi Iturralde', admin: false  },
    ];
  public added: string[] = [];
  x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 0; y2 = 0;

  @ViewChild('selector') selector: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  isRectangeVisible = false;
  isMouseDown = false;

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(ev) {
    this.dragStart = ev.clientY;
    this.isMouseDown = true;

  }

  @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp(ev) {
    this.dragStart = 0;
    this.dragOver = 0;
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    this.isRectangeVisible = false;
    this.isMouseDown = false;
  }

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(ev) {

    if(!this.isRectangeVisible && this.isMouseDown){
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
      this.x1 = ev.clientX;
      this.y1 = ev.clientY;
      this.isRectangeVisible = true;
    }

    this.x2 = ev.clientX;
    this.y2 = ev.clientY;
    this.reCalc();
  }

  reCalc() {
    const x3 = Math.min(this.x1, this.x2);
    const x4 = Math.max(this.x1, this.x2);
    const y3 = Math.min(this.y1, this.y2);
    const y4 = Math.max(this.y1, this.y2);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'left', x3 + 'px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'top', y3 + 'px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'width', x4 - x3 + 'px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.selector.nativeElement, 'height', y4 - y3 + 'px');
  }

  onSelecUser(item) {
        if(this.added.indexOf(item.name)===-1) { // or compare by id
            this.added = this.added.concat([item.name]);
        }
        else {
            this.added = this.added.filter((x) => item.name!==x); // or compare by id
        }

        item.selected = !item.selected ? true : false;
    }

    onMouseOver(ev, item) {
        if(ev.which!==1) {
            return false;
        }

        ev.preventDefault();

        if(ev.type==='mouseenter' && !item.selected) {
            this.dragOver = ev.clientY - this.dragStart > 0 ? 1:-1;
            this.onSelecUser(item);
            return false;
        }

        if(ev.type==='mouseleave') {
            if(this.dragOver===1 && ev.clientY < ev.target.offsetTop && item.selected) {
                console.log('desel...', item);
                this.onSelecUser(item);
                return false;
            }
            if(this.dragOver===-1 && ev.clientY > ev.target.offsetTop && item.selected) {
                console.log('desel...', item);
                this.onSelecUser(item);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #1:** 
https://plnkr.co/edit/d9aTb0E0OKFfTSIAM0MY?p=preview

Added option to select/unselect a user by a click.
For that,  no reset code needed.

```
  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(ev) {
    this.dragStart = ev.clientY;
    this.isMouseDown = true;
  }
```

Only div's click handler changed.

```
(click)="onSelecPersona(user, !user.selected)"
```

---

**INITIAL ANSWER:**
Here is modified code: https://plnkr.co/edit/QryFWtLQwNuGkrtzDehm?p=preview

It solves few issues:

**(1) HTML selection**: the "user-select" CSS should be on the "row" no on the "card"  because the selection starts at the "row" boundaries

```
.row {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.card-content {
  padding: 0;
}
```

**(2) Handling of selected divs:** initial implementation relies on mouse events on the user's div. That does not handle the case when "selector" rectangle never crosses  "user" div's boundaries (i.e. goes around but still within selection boundaries). 
My implementation calculates an overlap of a "selector" and "user" divs to determine if a user selected.

```
     <div class="card"
            #ucard   
            [attr.id]="user.name"
            [class.selected]="user.selected" 
            *ngFor="let user of users" 
            (click)="onSelecPersona(user, !user.selected)"
        >

    import {Component, NgModule, HostListener, Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core'
    ...
     @ViewChildren('ucard') components: QueryList<ElementRef>;
    ...
      // return true if two HTML elements overlap 
      overlap(e1:ElementRef, e2:ElementRef){
        var rect1 = e1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rect2 = e2.getBoundingClientRect();

        return !(
          rect1.top > rect2.bottom ||
          rect1.right < rect2.left ||
          rect1.bottom < rect2.top ||
          rect1.left > rect2.right
        ); 
      }

      // updates user selection based on the current "selector" 
      markSelected(){
        this.components.forEach(it=> {
          var overlaps: boolean = this.overlap(this.selector.nativeElement, it.nativeElement);
          this.onSelecPersona(this.users.find(u=> u.name == it.nativeElement.id), overlaps);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me alot. I'm still a noob and it is great to know something from an advanced person.

Can you tell me how can I select the card with a normal click without screw it up? with that it will be perfect.

Comment: Something like the demo, deselect the cards outside the cards and not in the cards, and select with the rectangle and normal click.

Comment: updated my answer, with new plunker link, that adds an option to select/unselect a user.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me alot. =)

Comment: Now I need to multi select the cards drawing the rect pressing the Ctrl button like the Demo, I will try to do it by my own, thanks.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with the code and it has been a little hard to me do the multi-select with the rectangle holding the ctrl button.

Comment: with the current state of the code, the only change left (for multi-select with Ctrl key)  is not to reset selected users, while dragging the mouse,   if envet.ctrlKey set to true.